# typeorm `cascade: true` is not functioning in mariadb

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I set `cascade: true` in the many-to-one relation. But when I checked the Mariadb database, the foreign key has "no action" in "on update" or "on delete" conditions. Is it bug, or can I solve it without `onDelete: "CASCADE", onUpdate: "CASCADE"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cascade: true` is something used by typeorm itself, and will not change your database schema. It means when modifying that relation from your code, typeorm will make sure to do the same in the database. If you want the constraint to be saved to the database itself you use `onDelete: "CASCADE"` and `onUpdate: "CASCADE"`